# Stretch WPF Dockpanel contents horizontally

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a DockPanel and it contains a ScrollViewer [ center aligned ] and a button on left and right .
My xaml is like

```
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
 <Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Left">Left</Button>
<Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Right">Right</Button>
  <ScrollViewer Name="scrollAreaPageView"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"    
</ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

And it generates the output as expected , but Left and right butons are not stretched fully to left and right to the ScrollViewer( They are on corners only).
The screen shot of output is [image]

How can i make it stretch fully to left and right of center scrollViewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DockPanel` may not be ideal in this scenario you may perhaps use `Grid` here with the desired column definition

sample

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button>Left</Button>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollAreaPageView"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Grid.Column="1">
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Grid.Column="2">Right</Button>
</Grid>
```

in above example the space available after subtracting the space required b

---

**Alternate approach**

I attempted to do it pure xaml, this approach will helo you achieve the desired without code behind. here is the example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=scrollAreaPageView}" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button>Left</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2">Right</Button>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="50,0"
                  Name="scrollAreaPageView"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

`Margin` in the `scrollAreaPageView` element defines minimum width of the buttons. give it a try and see if that helps

Comment: Will work , but if i set Scrollviewer to column 1 the scrollbars will never appear

Comment: does it have horizontal scrollbar? if yes then perhaps setting a max width on center column will do the trick

Comment: Yes its Horizontal scrollbar and setting max width will solve the issue. But assume i set maxwidth as PrimaryScreenWidth  , but when user resize the window to custom size mode the assumptions goes wrong.

Comment: @JMat, wondering if alternate approach worked for your needs?

Comment: in a way it works . With few more adjustments as per my specific requiremenst i manged to make it work ,Your approaches was really helpfu;